# Rendering generated png into JSF

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, pdf-generation, pdfbox

I built an image form PDF doc inside a JSF backing bean, i need to show image inside JSF page. I found that primefaces has a component named , I defined a variable:

```
    private StreamedContent pdfImage;
```

according to this example http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dynamicImage.jsf. In my code 
i built pdf using some data and apache PDFBox and save document into:

```
    private byte[] bytesPdf;
```

My jsf line is

```
<p:graphicImage value="#{myBean.pdfImage}" rendered="#{myBean.showImage}"/>
```

After that i call following method that tranform first PDF document page to  PNG i get:

```
public void buildPDFImage() throws IOException{
    ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    //Build bufferedImage from pdf bytearray
    InputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(bytesPdf);
    PDDocument archivo=new PDDocument();
    archivo=PDDocument.load(input);
    PDPage firstPage = (PDPage) archivo.getDocumentCatalog().getAllPages().get(0);
    BufferedImage bufferedImage = firstPage.convertToImage();   
    //File exit=new File("d:/exit.png"); if i do something like this and pass file as param to iowrite image is generated on file system
    try {
        ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", os);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }        
    pdfImage = new DefaultStreamedContent(new      ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()), "image/png");          
}
```

When i run my app after generate pdf image i get this trace

```
  GRAVE: Error Rendering View[/pages/apphuella.xhtml]
  java.lang.IllegalStateException: PWC3999: Cannot create a session after the response   has been committed
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.doGetSession(Request.java:2880)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.Request.getSession(Request.java:2577)
at org.apache.catalina.connector.RequestFacade.getSession(RequestFacade.java:920)
at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.getSession(SessionMap.java:235)
at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:126)
at com.sun.faces.context.SessionMap.put(SessionMap.java:61)
at org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImageRenderer.getImageSrc(GraphicImageRenderer.java:105)
at org.primefaces.component.graphicimage.GraphicImageRenderer.encodeEnd(GraphicImageRenderer.java:45)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1763)
at javax.faces.render.Renderer.encodeChildren(Renderer.java:168)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeChildren(UIComponentBase.java:845)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1756)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1759)
at
```

I would know if i´m using correctly  if don´t how could i use it to show generated png(and other images)?, also if there´s other option to show runtime generated images on JSF pages.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I remember that I had to put Managed Beans in Session scope. Try this

Answer (score 0):

At first, you need to keep the file a temporary directory. After that you should render the file again.
Try as below

Backing Bean

```
private String filePath;

public String filePath() {
    return filePath;
}

private String getSystemPath() {
    Object context = getFacesContext().getExternalContext().getContext();
    String systemPath = ((ServletContext)context).getRealPath("/");
    return systemPath;
}

public void buildPDFImage() throws IOException {
    // create any kind of file types.
    byte[] cotent =                             --> take byte array content of your files.
    Stirng fileName = "xxx.pdf" or "xxx.png"    --> your file name
    String dirPath = "/pdf/" or "/images/";     --> a directory to place created files.
    filePath = dirPath + fileName
    createFile(new File(getSystemPath() + filePath), content);
}

private void createFile(File file, byte[] content) {
    try {
        /*At First : Create directory of target file*/
        String filePath = file.getPath();
        int lastIndex = filePath.lastIndexOf("\\") + 1;
        FileUtils.forceMkdir(new File(filePath.substring(0, lastIndex)));

        /*Create target file*/
        FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        IOUtils.write(content, outputStream);
        outputStream.flush();
        outputStream.close();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Pages

```
<h:form enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <h:commandButton value="Create"/>
    <!-- Your Files is image -->
    <p:graphicImage value="#{myBean.filePath}"/>

    <!-- 
        Your Files is pdf. You need PDF Viewer plugin for your browser.
        My FireFox vesion is 20.0. It have default PDF Viewer.
        If PDF File cannot display on your browser, it is depond on browser setting also.
    -->
    <p:media value="#{myBean.filePath}" width="100%" height="300px"/>  
</h:form>
```